# Chrome 38 Extension - history.pushState

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

history.pushState is causing my extension to crash since update 38. Is there a new way to do this or is this a bug ?

Comment: Could you show a code snippet? I think that you're experiencing https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=396830.

Answer (score 1):

Any crash is a bug. Please file an issue at crbug.com/new, including a crash ID if possible, and follow up here with a link to the bug.